# SFDX: Is it possible to change a Text field to a Picklist?

Tags: salesforcedx, fields

I have a text field defined with the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>TextFieldThatWantsToBePicklist__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Text Field That Wants To Be Picklist</label>
    <length>255</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</CustomField>
```

I'd like it to become a Picklist, though. In order to do that, I modified the code with the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>TextFieldThatWantsToBePicklist__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Text Field That Wants To Be Picklist</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
    <valueSet>
        <restricted>true</restricted>
        <valueSetDefinition>
            <sorted>false</sorted>
            <value>
                <fullName>Picklist Value 1</fullName>
                <default>true</default>
                <label>Picklist Value 1</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>Picklist Value 2</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>Picklist Value 2</label>
            </value>
        </valueSetDefinition>
    </valueSet>
</CustomField>
```

However, when deploying, I'm receiving an error:

```
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH                                                                                            ERRORS                                                      
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\objects\CustomObject__c\fields\TextFieldThatWantsToBePicklist__c.field-meta.xml  Unsupported custom field type conversion attempted. (170:13)
```

**I'm aware that I can just change the field type in Setup**

However, as this change is about to be propagated across multiple environments, I'd prefer to achieve this task via SFDX / any other API-based method.

Is it actually possible or the only option is a pre-deployment manual step?

Comment: have you confirmed that text field isn't referenced somewhere? Put another way, if you try to do this in the UI - do you also get an error?

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves! So the funny thing is that before writing this post I checked that and indeed I had some Apex classes that were referencing this field (as I tried to delete it via the UI as well). I removed them, though, and the error persisted. So the interesting fact is that this error has a greater severance than the one about the field being used somewhere else. At least from the API perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is possible to do this with SFDX when the field type conversion is valid.
- You *can* convert a text to a picklist field, but **not** if you're looking to *restrict* the picklist options at the *same time*. It isn't possible to do that at all - in Setup UI or Metadata API.

*Why*?

During the conversion, existing values in the text field are pre-filled as values to the picklist (if done in Setup). Likewise, even if you don't set values based on existing data - they will be added as "Inactive Values" after the conversion. As such, there's a risk of creating invalid records when the existing text field can have *n* permutations of unique data.

[image]

As such, it seems there's a validation that blocks you from converting from text to a picklist with `Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set` selected. If you attempt to do it in the UI, you'll get the following

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "**Unsupported custom field type conversion attempted**.".

[image]

Your metadata currently is setting this

```xml
<valueSet>
    <restricted>true</restricted>
    <valueSetDefinition>
```

As such, you might want to make two different changes/deployments. One to convert the field and the other to restrict the values to those defined in the picklist (which you can then do afterwards). Just be aware about the potential for your data to become invalid if there were existing text values set for that field that are no longer options in the picklist.